# Does Windows Azure support adding extra instance to hosted service without restart other instances?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I already have a hosted service deployment which has 2 worker role instances, I want to add another  3 worker role instances to the same hosted service and at the same time, I don't want existing 2 worker role instances to be restarted.

While I can create another hosted service and put the new 3 instances into it, But, I have heard that Azure supports only 6 hosted services per account. Is that true?

As my application will use cloud drive function, so I will only create 1 instance per role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I am fully understanding your question here, but here are some ideas. 1) As has been noted, if you want to add instances of existing worker roles that can be done, and you should (I believe even in Java) be able to keep the existing instances from restarting. 
2) If you do want to create new roles (new definitions) it is possible to do this, and as suggested it is possible to go past the 'limit' of 6 services. And if you want to add new roles without restarting everything it is also possible - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx for more information.
3) You also mention a desire to run a single instance of each role because of the use of the 'cloud drive' I'm not sure I understand the issue here. If you are mounting the same drive it does not matter if it is mounted from a single instance of a role or many, or mounted by different roles - in any case it is only possible to mount it from one instance for writing, but you can mount it from multiple instances for reading.

I hope this is helpful. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your issues/questions and we'll see if we can find the right answer!

Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike, my purpose is to add new roles to existing hosted service. Your answer is almost what I want, however I found if want to add role to hosted service, will have to upgrade the whole hosted service, during the upgrade, all existing role will be restarted. I remember some document mentions that in-place upgrade will require at least 2 instance running per role. And, my application will write data to cloud drive, so I have only one instance per role.

Comment: You are correct with that - if you did have at least 2 instances per role then the upgrade domain would allow the upgrading of your roles without a complete shutdown. For example if there were two instances of each role, 1 instance would go down to be upgraded, leaving the other running. Once complete the second instance would be upgraded while the new instance remained running. But with a single instance you are not able to do this. Also remember that by running only 1 instance of each role you have no SLA's in place.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so the answer is "No" if I use cloud drive.
However my application is like a desktop application, it must write data to file. Seem Azure doesnot support such case very good.

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what your application is/does I'm not certain. But to write to a file on a disk will require using a Cloud Drive (if it must be durable), but you can utilize multiple role instances if you modify the application to save the data to Azure Storage (table or blob storage) and this can certainly be supported with multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

@Igor and @Mike have already given you great answers. Let me add a bit of detail to deal with your issue of Azure Drives.

You seem to be designing a single-instance-per-role configuration, just so you can have one writeable drive per instance. If that's indeed the case, this really doesn't scale well: it requires you to modify your project (and deploy a new package) every time you want to scale out or in. As an alternative, just create a unique drive per instance of the same role. Come up with a naming scheme based on instance ID (for a simple example: `/Drives/Instance0.vhd`). Upon instance startup, have the instance glean its ID and create a drive (or mount an existing one). The ID is available via `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add new roles into production slot, consider deploying new set of roles into staging slot, test and perform VIP swap.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure allows you to add instances on the fly without rebooting your other instances.  You will need to let Azure know about this during handling of RoleEnvironment_Changing event.

It is also true that by default, Windows Azure caps your limit of hosted services to 6 per account.  I believe you can increase that limit by calling their support and having the restriction lifted after they do a credit check...  However, the proper pattern to scale out is NOT to add additional services, but to add additional instances.

Here is an example that makes sure that your instances are not rebooted after new ones have been added:

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;
return base.OnStart();
}


private void RoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
{
    // If a configuration setting is changing
    if (e.Changes.Any(change => change is RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange))
    {
        // Set e.Cancel to true to restart this role instance
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Coincidentally, if you're looking to setup automatic scaling by adding or removing instances to your service, as demand increases or decreases, you can look into a 3rd party service called AzureWatch at http://www.paraleap.com

Comment: thanks, Igorek.
Two concerns: 1. what's the instances mean here? worker role or instance under worker role? For my case, I want to add new worker role because the new added instance will different with existing instance, they don't share their data.
2. As my project is java project, so we can not add c# code in to the project